# How to validate nulls - oracle etl testing?

Tags: oracle, validation, testing, null, etl

I am new to oracle and I would like to know how do we check the nulls in non null columns in oracle tables as part of the ETL testing process. (The two tables could be T1 and T2). Please let me know a sample query.

I have already tried

```
select count(*) from T2 where T2.column is Null;
```

Thanks, Santosh

Comment: It's [`t2.column is null`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Nulls.html#GUID-29B6554B-C948-4A8E-81C1-696A5128AAAD).

Comment: Or much better, ask your employer to hire a database guy or gal..

Comment: @KaushikNayak I am sorry if this question is troubling you.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson My bad. I missed that in the question. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

'=' operator can not be used while comparing to null. Replace '=' to 'is' as per below query.
 select count(*) from T2 where T2.column  is  Null;

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is column name: id in the table record, and id should not contain any null value. Query to check this is:

```sql
select id from record where id is null;
```